# Should I set copy local false for commonly referenced assemblies in asp.net mvc applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

My organisation has a few assemblies defined for business logic stuff. We are trying to set up  continuous integration for these common libraries, as well as maintain a project template that references them. This will allow us to bang out small maintenance applications relatively quickly.

The goal was to plop these dlls in one folder by version and have them be resolved at runtime in the Global.asax. I'm finding various things break if they aren't copied local, e.g. strongly typed razor views.

Are there any real benefits in having them in one shared directory, or is the best practice to build the main applications while referencing the shared project source and copying local?

My coworkers believe that the shared location will make it easy to fix bugs later if business logic changes. I feel that we will never have a need to globally change some object or service, and if we did, we'd have to touch every app anyways to handle the change.

Comment: Keep in mind, pulling them out of the bin directory (Copy Local) will require them to be in the `Global Assembly Cache`. Unless you're going to oull the correct versions into the bin directory at build time.

Comment: @Frazell That's the problem. No one intends to GAC, and no one wants to copy local. They expect it to work from a shared directory on the disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publish your shared DLL's in a [NuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) to a [Local NuGet server](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)! This way each relying app can have an explicit dependency on a specific version of your package.

Comment: +1 This. Works great and automatically adds the references, etc. can even add config and code changes, too.

Comment: Just to be clear, this method still means that the shared DLLs will be Copy Local = True?

Comment: NuGet handles this for you, but yes it does specify Copy Local = True since these external DLL's will be referenced by your running code (NuGet also modifies your .csproj files to have the appropriate references).  If it did not copy them to your output directory, you would have to rely on something more invasive like the GAC

Comment: Seems easy enough, I'll give this a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place your DLL on ONE shared common folder. This is to prevent on any future issues that you may encounter where in the application cannot resolve or "confused" on what DLL it should use.